# My JFileChooser doesn't work the second time I use it

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

So, I'm trying to call getFile() which opens a JFileChooser. It works the first time it is called, but not the second.

I have a while(!done) loop to act as a menu in my main and one of the options gets the file and does something to it. It works fine the first time, but it gets stuck at `if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)` the second time I try to do it from the menu. What is even more weird is that when I debug that line, it will work multiple times. I'm also positive the dialogue box isn't hiding somewhere the second time. The only suspicion I can find is something is going on in the event dispatch thread, but that is above my level of understanding. So, I guess I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about JFileChoosers?

```
public  void getFile()
 throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{ 
    JFileChooser myChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt files", "txt");
    myChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = myChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File myFile=myChooser.getSelectedFile();
        this.myFile=myFile;     
        String tempFileName= myFile.getName();
        fileName= tempFileName.substring(0, (tempFileName.length()-4));
        System.out.println("File Picked: " +fileName);
        this.fileName=fileName;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Okay, here is something that recreates the problem:

Tester:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
 throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done)
        {   System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1 - GetFile");
            System.out.println("2 - Exit");
            int choice= Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());

            if (choice ==1)
             { System.out.println("GetFile ");     
             Chooser myChooser=new Chooser();
             myChooser.getFile();
             System.out.println("done");
             }
                else if( choice ==2)
                { System.out.println("Good Bye"); done=true;}       
                        else System.out.println("Invalid choice");

        } while (!done);

                        System.exit(0);  
    }
}
```

Program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class Chooser {
public  void getFile()
 throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{ 
    JFileChooser myChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = myChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("loop marker");
        File myFile=myChooser.getSelectedFile();    
        String tempFileName= myFile.getName();
        System.out.println("File Picked: " +tempFileName);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"while(!done) loop to act as a menu in my main"* Now I'm just scared.  Dumping an out of context code snippet on us and expecting us to magically know how it works and what's wrong with it is magical thinking. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It seriously sounds like you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: You're mixing a Swing program with a console program in a dangerous way. Better to stick with one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your specific problem. The code works for me; however, it's still broken, because it is wrong to use Swing components from the main thread.

Try switching to the event dispatch thread before you do anything else (this is made unfortunately more messy by your exceptions that need to be rethrown):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    main(args);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```